# Deleting the files every time before running the code again in python

Tags: python

I have a program say `check.py`, to run this program I need 5-6 supporting files inside that program, say `1.py`,`2.data`,`3.test`,`4.train`,`5.txt`. After I run that code using `python3 check.py` 60 new files will be created as output. So before running the `check.py` once again I want to clear all the previously created 60 files using a python script.

The steps what I am thinking to do so is I want to create a list of the needed files in that folder. For an example in the above cases those are : `1.py`,`2.data`,`3.test`,`4.train`,`5.txt` and `check.py`. Then I want to delete all the remaining files which are not in this list. Can I do like this? Please help me out.

Comment: Yes, looks like a workable solution.

Comment: I'd suggest making subfolders, e.g. `input` and `output` and just deleting whole output folder once you're finished.

Comment: @DevangSanghani can you please help me by saying how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would create the new files in a subfolder and then delete that one when it is no longer of interest. Will be less messy.
Otherwise os.listdir() will give you a list of all files in a directory. Just need to remove the ones you want to keep.